# WordPress: Get checked/selected taxonomy label

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox, custom-post-type

I am trying to figure out how to get taxonomy(checkboxes) label from a custom post type that is checked/selected to show on the single custom post. The code below is outputting all the taxonomies not just the checked ones.

```
 function get_terms_chekboxes($taxonomies, $args) {
   $terms = get_terms($taxonomies, $args);
   foreach($terms as $term){
    $output .= $term->name ;
   }
   return $output;
  }
  echo get_terms_chekboxes('genre', $args = array('post_type' => 'movie','hide_empty'=>false));
```

How to get checked taxonomy labels.

Thanks.

[Reference](https://gist.github.com/abrahamvelazquez/5843383)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this function for retrieving the `term_names` of single custom posts assigned to it.

```
$term_array = array();
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'genre', array("fields" => "all"));
foreach($term_list as $term_single) {
    $term_array[] = $term_single->name ; //do something here
}
echo implode(", ",$term_array);
```

where `$post->ID` is the ID of the single custom post & '`genre`' is your taxonomy slug.

I hope, this may be helpful to you.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I needed. Thank you. Any idea how to put a comma after every value ?

Comment: Please find my updated code & let me know if you have any query.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the help.